# Nontrivial U(1) bundles of a 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

If G is a Lie group which is (1) a connected,
(2) simply connected
(3) compact,
then a G bundle on a 3-manifold is necessarily trivial.

However, U(1) bundle does not satisfy this (2) simply connected criterion.

Can we construct explicit nontrivial U(1) bundles of a 3-manifold? For the following examples:

> - $S^3$
> - $\mathbb{T}^3$
> - $S^2 \times S^1$
> - $D^2 \times S^1$
> - $D^3$

($D^d$ is a $d$-disk.)

It looks that it is easier to do on $S^2 \times S^1$ if we consider a nontrivial Chern number $c_1$ over the $S^2$ (?). How about other cases?

Comment: $U(1)$-bundles are classified by $H^1(-, U(1)) \cong H^2(-, \mathbb{Z})$, so you just have to compute $H^2$ and this is straightforward in all of your examples using the Kunneth formula.

Comment: The same way that the homogeneous lens spaces $ SU_2 /C_n \cong L_{n,1} $ give you all the nontrivial $ U^1 $ principal bundles over $ S^2 $ I believe the quotients $ U_2/C_n $ should give you all the nontrivial $ U_1 $ principal bundles over $ S^3 $. Here by by $ C_n $ I mean the $ n $ element cyclic subgroup of $ SU_2 $ generated by the diagonal matrix $ diag(\zeta_n,\overline{\zeta_n}) $ where $ \zeta_n $ is a primitive $ n $th root of unity.